# neo4j: Connection closed after few minutes: defunct connection Address

Tags: python, neo4j

I have a server in which the connection is opened (python):

```
    self._driver: Driver = GraphDatabase.driver(credentials["uri"], auth=(credentials["user"], credentials["password"]), max_connection_lifetime=3600*24*30, keep_alive=True)
```

I run some requests and it works all perfectly. The requests are run by using the function:

```
def __exe_query(self, query: str):
    with self._driver.session() as session:
        session.run(query).consume()
```

Despite these queries do not return anything relevant I added .consume() based on this post https://community.neo4j.com/t/error-while-loading-data-in-neo4j-python-driver/7413/7.

I wait 4-5 minutes (while the server is running waiting for other requests), I run the exact same requests, and **I get the error:**

> Failed to read from defunct connection Address(host='****', port=**)

I also tried with max_connection_lifetime=-1.

I am working with python 3.7.0 with these libraries versions: neo4j==1.7.2 neobolt==1.7.9 neotime==1.7.4 as suggested by https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-python-driver/issues/293. 
It does not work in Win10 and Linux Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

Thanks for your help and attention,
Vittorio